# Is it possible to create a responsive design in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

We are upgrading to SharePoint 2013 and we want to make a new design to take advantage of the new features.

But is it possible to create a responsive design in SharePoint 2013?
(In both 2007 and 2010 it was almost impossible)

Comment: hi, maybe this video will be useful to someone: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn1x7lGJtIg

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/

A quick google search will give you a good amount of results on the subject.